# SELECT statement returning null after INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement in same transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am opening a MySQL database transaction using JPA (Hibernate) and executing the following code inside that:

```
UserConfig userConfig = this.findUserConfig(appId, userId, devicePlatform);
if(userConfig == null){
    userConfig = this.addDefaultUserConfig(appId, userId, devicePlatform);
    if (userConfig == null) logger.error("userConfig must not be null")
}
```

I am getting "userConfig must not be null" log sometimes in production. So I wanted to know why it is happening?

UserConfig entity looks like below:

```
@Table(name = "user_config")
public class UserConfig extends TemporalModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "app_id")
    private String appId;

    @Column(name = "device_platform")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Platform devicePlatform;

    @Column(name = "payer")
    private Boolean payer;

    @Column(name = "winning_balance")
    private BigDecimal winningBalance;

    @Column(name = "games_eligibility_count")
    private Integer gamesEligibilityCount;
}
```

findUserConfig method implementation:

```
public UserConfig findUserConfig(String appId, String userId, Platform devicePlatform) {
    EntityManager em = threadContextProvider.currentThreadContext().getEm();
    String queryS = "SELECT u FROM UserConfig u WHERE u.userId = :userId and u.appId = :appId";
    TypedQuery<UserConfig> q = em.createQuery(queryS, UserConfig.class)
            .setParameter("userId", userId)
            .setParameter("appId", appId);


    List<UserConfig> userConfig = q.getResultList();
    if (userConfig == null || userConfig.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return userConfig.get(0);
}
```

addDefaultUserConfig method implementation:

```
UserConfig addDefaultUserConfig(String appId, String userId, Platform devicePlatform) {
    EntityManager em = threadContextProvider.currentThreadContext().getEm();
    String queryStr = "INSERT INTO user_config values ( null, :userId , :appId , :devicePlatform, :winningBalance , :payer ," +
            ":ratedOnAppStore , :ratedOnPlayStore , :gamesEligibilityCount , now() , now() ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = now() ;";

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr)
        .setParameter("userId", userId)
        .setParameter("appId", appId)
        .setParameter("devicePlatform", devicePlatform == null ? null:devicePlatform.name())
        .setParameter("payer", 0)
        .setParameter("winningBalance", "0.00")
        .setParameter("ratedOnAppStore", 0)
        .setParameter("ratedOnPlayStore", 0)
        .setParameter("gamesEligibilityCount", 0);
    int affectedRows = q.executeUpdate(); //not coming 0
    
    UserConfig userConfig = findUserConfig(appId, userId, devicePlatform);
    if (userConfig == null) {
        logger.debug("addDefaultUserConfig: userConfig is null");
    }
    return userConfig;
}
```

Indexes on table are:

- PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
- UNIQUE KEY `user_config` (`user_id`,`app_id`)

Also affectedRows's value was not zero when addDefaultUserConfig method was returning null.

One more observation:

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = now()` - I am updating updated_at because otherwise addDefaultUserConfig method was returning null more frequently when I had `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = :userId`.

One more observation:

With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = :userId`, addDefaultUserConfig method was always returning null if insertion was not being done by this transaction.

Comment: If you changed your entity primary key to be the natural userId and appId composite ID, JPA would pretty much handle this for you with its merge api. Otherwise, what does your query execution return for AffectedRows, what is the constraint(s) you've got on that table, and why do you have devicePlatform being passed into findUserConfig when the query is only using appId and userId? I'd guess you have multiple unique indexes - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Indexes on table are:

PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE KEY user_config (user_id,app_id)

ALSO affectedRows's value was not zero when addDefaultUserConfig method was returning null. Also devicePlatform passed into findUserConfig method is useless.

Comment: @Chris updated question with more description.

Comment: @chris `If you changed your entity primary key to be the natural userId and appId composite ID, JPA would pretty much handle this for you with its merge api` -> if two threads concurrently try to insert, then merge api will throw duplicate exception. so to prevent that exception we are doing ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE